# Why i am getting the error page not found in the nginx?

Tags: nginx

Getting error in Nginx --> 404 page not found. I have task to host the website using the nginx. I have read the basic things and I have host the website, but getting the error. The following are the trouble shooting:

```
    # nginx -t 
    nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
    nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

```
    systemctl status nginx
    ● nginx.service - The nginx HTTP and reverse proxy server
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
      Active: active (running) since Thu ; 17h ago
      Process: 1482 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/nginx -s reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Process: 32393 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Process: 32389 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Process: 32387 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/rm -f /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Main PID: 32395 (nginx)
       CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
               ├─ 1484 nginx: worker process
               ├─ 1485 nginx: worker process
               └─32395 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
```

```
    curl -vv https://testing.abc.com
    getting ssl certificate information.
```

```
    curl -k https://testing.abc.com
    # getting error --> 404 page not found
```

I have check fallowing things

1. in the conf.d folder i have check root path of website folder,
2. in the main nginx.conf file i have mention the root path.
3. remove the nginx packages and again install it, but still getting the same error

Comment: Please format your logs, It's impossible to read unformatted logs.

Comment: Did you restart nginx? Could you add your config file?

Comment: yes i have stop and start the nginx service. Also i have restart the nginx service.